# Every time I add "border:0" on my hr element, many of my hr elements stop displaying completely

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

Basically I'm using a series of hr elements to section off my web page.  This is what my CSS looks like below:

```
hr{
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: .1px;
    width: 95%;
    margin:15px;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    border:0;
}
```

The weird thing is that every time I add 'border' it causes over a half of my elements to stop displaying on the page completely.  What could the issue be here?  How should I fix this?

P.S. the same thing happens if I use "border-width:0px" as well.

Comment: Please provide us with a full example of the unwanted behavior. Show us the HTML too.

Comment: Exactly what does 0.1px look like?

Comment: Maybe you meant: `height: 1px;` ?

Comment: `hr` elements **are** borders....if you remove them they disappear.

Comment: Please  also read this article: http://www.sovavsiti.cz/css/hr.html Unfortunately I am not sure how old is the article but it say  border handling on <hr> depends on browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem certainly comes from the `height: .1px;` if you remove the border, the element will be lower than half a pixel in size! Since a pixel cannot be cut into pieces, browsers will tend to simply not display it, or display a full pixel. Depending on... not exactly sure on what.